# Is there a way to highlight the Increment Digit in a DecimalUpDown control?

Tags: wpf, numericupdown

I'm using the WPF extended toolkit DecimalUpDown control. I allow the user to change the Increment property of this control in a couple of ways. I would like to be able to give them feedback as to which digit will change when the up/down buttons are clicked (or the mouse wheel is scrolled). I would like to change some property of the digit that would increment. Changing the color, the background, underlining, bolding, pretty much anything would be acceptable but I get the feeling there is no native support for this, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be possible, but I ended up just using tooltips to help. If the user hovers over the control it shows the current increment. If the tooltip is showing and any of the methods for modifying the increment are used, the tooltip will update in real time with the current increment. Not perfect but seems to help.